# How to chain matrix transformation operations?

Tags: three.js

Why doesn't chaining `makeTranslation` methods on `matrix` object work?

```
      boxMesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false
      boxMesh.matrix.makeTranslation(30, 0, 0)
      boxMesh.matrix.makeTranslation(30, 0, 0)
```

the mesh moves only 30 units on **x** axis, not 60

but when I use `applyMatrix` method everything works as expected:

```
      boxMesh.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(30, 0, 0))
      boxMesh.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(30, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Matrix4.makeTranslation()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Matrix4.makeTranslation) creates a pure translation matrix. All existing matrix elements are overwritten. Hence, the method is not intended to apply a translation to an existing transformation matrix.

[Object3D.applyMatrix()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.applyMatrix) works different since it multiplies the given matrix with the object's local transformation matrix. This leads to a combination of the given and the existing transformation.

`three.js R104`